# 'docker" command cannot be found in this WSL1 distro

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, hyperledger-fabric, wsl-2, ibm-blockchain

While attempting to install, in `VS Code`, the [Fabric samples and binaries](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/install.html)  through the `curl` command :

I've encountered the following error, as soon as Fabric `docker` images are pulled :

```
The command 'docker' could not be found in this WSL1 distro. We recommend to convert this distro into 
WSL 2 and activate the WSL integration in Docker Desktop settings.
```

[image]

N.B: `Docker version 20.10.0-beta1`

Thus any relevant feedback, not impacting the usage of the `IBM Blockchain Platform` `v.1.0.39` (e.g. prerequisites installed), would highly be appreciated.

Best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the *Docker Desktop WSL 2 backend* [guide](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl/).

Specifically, you need to convert your Ubuntu distribution to WSL2 (it is currently WSL1).  To do so, see Step 6 in the [Install section](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl/#install):

To upgrade your existing Linux distro to v2, run:

`wsl.exe --set-version Ubuntu 2`

Either that, or create a new WSL instance by backing up the WSL1 version (`wsl --export`) and then importing it into a new copy (`wsl --import`).  See `wsl --help` for the parameters needed.

Then proceed with the rest of the Docker installation instructions.

Comment: Thank you very much for for your feedback.

Comment: Any suggestions on what to do if you can't upgrade to WSL2?

Comment: The command in my case was "wsl.exe --set-version Ubuntu-18.04 2" . In other words one has give exact distribution name, not just Ubuntu. The exact name can be seen in the output of "wsl -l -v"

Answer (score 0):

in my case, resolved by enabling the WSL2 distro option in the docker settings.

> As the log says (in your qusetion)
> `We recommend to convert this distro into  WSL 2 and activate the WSL integration in Docker Desktop settings.`

1. in Docker Settings
2. go `Resources`
3. go `WSL INTEGRATION`
4. check `Enable integration with my default WSL distro`
5. `Apply & Restart`

[image: docker Settings]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, the one from ```NotTheDr01ds```  (see above) has worked in my case.

Comment: I don't have the `WSL Integration` option in my Docker Desktop

Answer (score 0):

[image]

### I faced the same issue and solved it by navigating to: **docker desktop > Resources > wsl integration** then choose the right distro for integrating docker with.